# How can I see when was the Drupal view last updated?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a production database. Our team have done few changes in UAT environment in Drupal views. Now I want to see which views were modified in development so that we can port the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can export each view and compare it with the one in production
[Export view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuaBG.jpg)

Comment: That is what we do but exporting each view and comparing is a tedious task.